# How can I append dynamic data to infinite scroll in masonry

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading

I have an mobile web application. In this I have used masonry for pinning images. Now I want to implement infinite scrolling feature in my application. For this I have tried jquery.infnitescroll.js. 
But I want to load the images dynamicaly using ajax calls. How Can I implemnt this. Is any other way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Check the jquery part of [this tutorial](http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/auto-load-records-on-page-scroll)

And you have to adapt your server side depending on your server side techno/language. (PHP in the tutorial)